# Using a loop in java to up load a big file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Java and am trying to perform a test to monitor how long it takes for a file  to be uploaded and validated.

I need to carry out this process several times on the same file, so I used a loop. This works very well for a small file but for a large file where the page needs to refresh several times before all the elements can be displayed, and because the file has the same name, it fails. How do I specify that the top role should be targeted.

Below is the code

```
         this.openUrl("");
    this.login("", "");

         for(int i=1; i<11; i++)



this.uploadbtn("C:\\Documents\\Performance\\Panther New.csv");


  long lStartTime = new Date().getTime(); // start time
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
try{
  System.out.println(this.getTimeStamp());
    Thread.sleep(2000);



    while (!driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/span[text()='Panther.csv']/../..//a[@title='Review']")).isDisplayed()) {
     driver.navigate().refresh();
        }

    System.out.println(this.getTimeStamp());


   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/span[text()='Panther.csv']/../..//a[@title='Review']")).click();  
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Isn't it related to `Selenium WebDriver`. Dont use `Thread.sleep` instead use some `implicit` or `explicit` wait time.

Comment: correct don't use Thread.sleep